# FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage() not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a new to ASP.Net. Please, explain me what I need to add.
I clicked this page before login to take user to login page by "FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();". But After Page_Load , it goes to "dsRequestList_Selecting". I assumed it goes directly to Login page, but here some reason it goes to login page after dsRequestList_Selecting(). What do I need to do?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
            }
        }
    }

protected void dsRequestList_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
    {
       //Selecting
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't go this way.

Use Web.config (or, for MVC, the `[Authorize]` attribute) to secure pages. You don't need this kind of code and you don't want the susceptibility to errors (in every page) that it brings.

You only need

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
       <authorization>
         <deny users="?" /> 
       </authorization>

       ...
    </system.web>

    ....
</configuration>
```

to secure *all* your pages in the same folder as this web.config. The loginform is automatically excepted.

Answer (score 1):

Even though an answer has been accepted, I wanted to add to this to clarify and answer the original question.

The reason why additional code on the page is being executed is due to the specifics of how `FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage()` works.

From the [FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Unlike the HttpResponse.Redirect method, this method does not end the request by calling HttpResponse.End. This means that code that follows the RedirectToLoginPage method call will run.

What [Henk Holterman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60761/henk-holterman) said is accurate though, you shouldn't be handling authentication in a page itself, or ideally in the code at all (recompiling just to change access is silly).  The web.config example he posted is sufficient.

Also, I'll post a revised version of your code that wouldn't allow `dsRequestList_Selecting` to be called but still handle authentication at the page level (which again, is unadvised).

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //No need to check IsPostBack if your action is the same either way.
    if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
        //Note: Using CompleteRequest() over Response.End() is significantly quicker
        //This is because it avoids raising the ThreadAbortException.
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        //So if you use CompleteRequest(), you want the return statement after.
        //Unless you wrap the rest of the Page_Load logic in an else statement, like the alternate solution below            
        return;
    }
    //All other Page_Load logic
}
```

Alternate, more costly way (due to exception):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
        Response.End();
    }
    else
    {
        //All other Page_Load logic
    }
}
```